# {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.} C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dotnet-httpclient, azure-maps

I have a C# code which uses HttpClient.SendAsync method to make an API call to azure maps API. When I run this code, I'm getting following error.

> {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection
> was forcibly closed by the remote host.}

I searched in multiple websites for solution and tried the following piece of code just before making API request

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)768 | (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

But there's no use. I'm still getting the error.

I tried to set security protocol in different ways as follows:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
```

Even these pieces of code didn't help. I'm still getting same error.

I set those security protocol types using powershell like

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I tried powershell Invoke-RestMethod command as well. I'm getting similar error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An
> unexpected error occurred on a send

I didn't understand

1. What's meant by System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol and what is the use of it
2. What's meant by System.Net.SecurityProtocolType, what's the use of it, what type to choose for my requirement
3. or am I getting this error because of different problem

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

> What's meant by System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol and what is the use of it

- System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Gets or sets the security protocol used by the ServicePoint objects managed by the ServicePointManager.
- For new connections, this property specifies which version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use; existing connections are not altered.

> What's meant by System.Net.SecurityProtocolType

- It Specifies the security protocols which are supported by the Schannel security package.
- This enumeration defines the range of values that can be used to specify the transport security protocol to utilise.

This error usually indicates that the remote side of the connection has been closed (normally by sending a TCP/IP 'RST' packet). If you're using a third-party application, the following are the most likely causes:

- You are sending malformed data to the application (which could include sending an HTTPS request to an HTTP server)
- For some reason, the network connectivity between the client and the server is failing.
- You caused the third-party application to crash by triggering a bug in it.

To narrow down the problem, use Wireshark to examine exactly what is going on on the wire. Also this may be due to Security Protocol support issue,  try upgrading to the latest .NET framework Version as it is a connection issue.